# How to set auto height for flexWrap

Tags: react-native

I have a screen named SelectedTimings in my project in which i have to show all the selected timings by the user. When the time is selected more than 3 times, values have gone away from the screen. So i used flexWrap:wrap to break them into multiple lines. But the broken lines overlapping with the below objects.

```
     <View style={styles.cutomTimeContainer}>
     {
      whenAndTotalTimes.type == 'Daily' && 
      selectedTimes.map((item, key) =>
      <View style={styles.customTime} key={key}>
              <CustomDailyTime
               mode={whenAndTotalTimes.type}
               showHour={item?.hour}
               showMin={item?.minutes}
               showAmpm={item?.ampm}
               selectedColor={isClicked}
              />
      </View>
      )
   }
   </View>

    cutomTimeContainer:
    {
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginVertical: 10,
        alignContent: 'stretch',
        // height: 100
    },

    customTime:
    {
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 10
    },
```

Is there any way to set the auto height for flexWrap? Please find the below image for ref. Thanks in Advance. [image]

Comment: Could you share the jsx and the associated styles?

Comment: updated my post

Comment: Need the jsx as well, since the styles all depend on the view heirachy. A simple reproducable example would be best. You can try setting flex:1 to set the flex grow property.

Comment: Does the containing card have a fixed size set?

Comment: No height values added to any style.

Comment: In that case, this should already work, you can see a dummy verion [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-varahamihira-295iz?file=/src/App.js). If you post the rest of the code(of the entier card) It would be easier to identify the issue.

Comment: Okay Let me try